# R - Linking two different sets of coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates

I have two data sets - let's call them 'plot'(734 rows) and 'stations'(62 rows). A while ago I worked out that this code should let me link each 'plot' to its nearest 'station' based on their coordinates

data set is a little like this - (but without the headers of Long and Lat)

```
plot - Long  Lat         stations - Long  Lat
       13.2  60.5                   14.6  55.4
       15.4  62.6                   15.5  62.9
       15.6  62.4                   16.4  58.9
       16.5  58.7                   19.3  64.0
       16.5  58.5


#print results to "results.csv"
sink("results.csv")

#identifyl long + lat coords of each data set
p_coord<-SpatialPoints(plot[,c(1,2)])  
s_coord<-SpatialPoints(stations[,c(1,2)])

#link coordinates  
require(FNN)
g = get.knnx(coordinates(s_coord), coordinates(p_coord),k=1)
str(g)
plot(s_coord_2, col=2, xlim=c(-1e5,6e5))
plot(p_coord, add=TRUE)
segments(coordinates(p_coord)[,1], coordinates(p_coord)[,2], coordinates(s_coord[g$nn.index[,1]])[,1], coordinates(s_coord[g$nn.index[,1]])[,2])

#print result in results.csv
print(g)
```

I've since realised that the results i get are slightly wrong - for example plots #3 and #4 are linked to station #4, when it would be more applicable that plots #4 and #5 are linked to station #4.

So this leads me to think that something in the code is slightly off, but only by one row

would appreciate any comments on my code, or am equally interested into suggestions on simpler ways to connect two series of coordinates
Thanks

Comment: "that plots #4 and #5 are linked to station #4.".. shouldn't be station #3?

Answer (score 0):

What is your coordinate reference system? Are these points in Scandinavia?
Anyway, you could go with the geosphere package and use `distHaversine` or
`distVincentyEllipsoid`(more precise) to get the distances:

```
plot <- data.frame(Lon = c(13.2,15.4,15.6,16.5,16.5),
                   Lat = c(60.5,62.6,62.4,58.7,58.5))

stations <- data.frame(Lon = c(14.6,15.5,16.4,19.3),
                       Lat = c(55.4,62.9,58.9,64))

p_coord <- SpatialPoints(plot[,c(1,2)])  
s_coord <- SpatialPoints(stations[,c(1,2)])

library(geosphere)
apply(p_coord@coords, 1, function(x) {
  which.min(distHaversine(p1 = x, p2 = s_coord@coords))
})
```

The output will be

```
[1] 3 2 2 3 3
```

which means that plot 1 is close to station 3, plot 2 is linked to station 2 and so on.